# Flutter Container not shown because of borderRadius?

Tags: flutter

I added borders on 3 of 4 sides of my Container. It is not shown if I'm adding a borderRadius in the BoxDecoration. Without the borderRadius it is visible with the borders and the text in it. How can I add a borderRadius to the Container without it being hidden?

```
[...]
    Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              height: 85,
              width: 330,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                  right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                  bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                ),
                // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Example text! Example text! Example text! Example text!',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontFamily: 'Dosis'),
              ),
            ),
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get reference from below code..

```
body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0)
            ) ,
            border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
              right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
              bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: I don't want the Container to have a background. It should have a black border with a white background. In your code, it doesn't have a border, only the radius. There should also only be a border on the top, right and bottom.

Comment: The border is still visible on the left side. It should look like a U, rotated by 90°.

Comment: then please reomove this 2 lines topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(25.0) and add it according to your preference

Comment: My problem is the border on the left side which is always shown. Is it possible to remove the border on the left side but not on the three other sides?

Comment: Please send me pic

Comment: Like this, the entire Container is hidden

Answer (score 0):

You can use container over container

```
Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.w),bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.w)),
                        color: pinkLiteBorderColor,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1).copyWith(bottom: 1),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.w),bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.w)),
                          color: pinkLiteColor,
                        ),
```